# Issues downloading Eclipse ADT bundle

Tags: eclipse, adt

I'm having issues downloading the correct Eclipse version. I downloaded the ADT Eclipse bundle from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. When opening Eclipse, the splash screen looks like the regular purple Eclipse Juno screen instead of the black and green Android Developer Tools splash screen. I've uninstalled and re-downloaded the bundle multiple times and I'm having no luck installing the correct version. Please help as this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Could be many of the reasons.
But most common is:

```
Eclipse requires a JVM to run and does not include one in the download. You need to grab a VM yourself; the Eclipse downloads page has pointers to where you can get one. You may have a VM, but Eclipse cannot find it. To avoid possible conflicts, always specify the VM you are using with the -vm command-line argument.
```

For detail refer : [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_I_unzipped_Eclipse,_but_it_won%27t_start._Why%3F)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Eclipse knows of my JVM. I've downloaded and used ADT before. I had to re-install it for some reason. When I downloaded the ADT bundle from the link and open it, Juno ends up opening instead of ADT.